# php database - storing 30 days of data for each user

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to set up a database to record the last 30 days of information for each user. The data will be recorded once a day (i.e. by a cron job) and will be the value of an item (i.e. constantly changes).

What would be the best way to structure this? I was thinking of setting a table and then just storing the 30 days in the table and deleting the 31st day as I add the new day with the cron job (and shifting all of the others up one day) but this doesn't seem very efficient..

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is store the current date with each entry, then in your cron job, delete all entries that are greater than thirty days old.

For example (with MySQL),

```
DELETE FROM user_statistics WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), date_of_record) > 30;
```

Answer (score 2):

Store the user data with its own **date** and delete the oldest when you exceed your limit.  No need to shift anything.

Answer (score 2):

I'd log by actual date using a `DATE` column. You can query up "last 30 days" pretty easily in MySQL.

As for purging, the cron job can delete anything older than 30 days pretty easily as well. Or, since it's so easy to ignore anything older than 30 days, you might even choose to not delete older records (at least not every day).